# Dividing float by int and storing as float - Division by zero

Tags: c, floating-point, int, division

I have the following piece of code which does not want to devide `up`, which is declared as a `float`, by `down`, which is declared as an `int`. I have tried casting `down` to a float but that does not work either. 
The output I get is 10 times `inf`.

```
int main(void) {
    float x = 0.1, y = 0.0;

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        float up = exp(x, n);
        int down = fac(n);

        y = up / down;

        printf("%f\n", y);

        x += 0.1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me find the (huge) mistake in this piece of code? Both the `exp(x,n)` and `fac(n)` return the right value type to `up` and `down`.

These are the two functions `exp`and `fac`

```
float exp(float x, int n) {
    float power = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        power *= x;
    }
    return power;
}

int fac(int n) {
    int fac = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        fac *= i;
    }
    return fac;
}
```

Comment: Please include both functions! Also try to cast the return of the functions to int and float (e.g. `float up = (float) exp(x, n);
        int down = (int) fac(n);`) Does that do the trick?

Comment: What does `fac()` do?

Comment: And do not name your own function `exp`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dividing by 0:

```
int fac = 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    fac *= i; /* This will be 0 since you start from i=0. */
}
return fac;
```

You probably just want to start from `1` instead.

Comment: Thanks. What a horrible mistake not thinking about dividing by zero. Now I do get the right output. Let's get back to work keeping that in mind.